# Recursive function with event listener in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have written a function which is recursively called. I have maintained an array in which values are pushed with a listener of an event. But the problem is function is returned first without array increment and the listener is executed later.

```
public function getAllChilds(seltem:XML, allChilds:Array): Array 
{ 
     if(//the childs of selected item if need to retrive from server)                               
     var   viewChildrenJobsService : HTTPService = new HTTPService(); 
     viewChildrenJobsService.url = // here is my url ; 

 viewChildrenJobsService .addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, function(event:ResultEvent):void { 
    // now on this result event i got all childs of selected item.
    for each(var childJob :XML in seltem.children())    
    {
         allChilds.push(childJob); 
          if (//the childs of childJob need to retrive from server) 
            allChilds = getAllHierarchicalChilds(childJob, allChilds); 
    }
 }); 

 return allChilds; 
}
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem so that the function will return after the completion of the event?

Answer (score 0):

ok , you are returning allchilds before the Result Event. You erase the original question ;) ,  so i dont remember if your problem was this.
Try to split the function : First the request, then get the value of allChild.

and yes ... is better to write (and paste) good formatted code : its easier to understand.

Comment: yes. Now I have splited the function but still I am facing the same problem. The function is first returning the allChilds (as null) before elements getting added. I debugged it but found that the event is caught later.

Comment: Of course event will be handled later. You can't do it this way. I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but I suggest you to read about [data providers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fb8.html) and [Using HTTPService with xml](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/AccessingData/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fdd.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7b7a). Or if you will be more specific maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: splitting the function alone dont work : in result handler, you have to call the second function , after you set allchilds. pls repost the question